# How to get count_id and rating_evarate from table?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, average

How to get count_id and rating_evarate from table?

I want to count the id and get rating evarate from the table bellow .
how can I do it in mysql .

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `rating`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `rating`;
CREATE TABLE `rating` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of rating
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `rating` VALUES ('1', '5');
INSERT INTO `rating` VALUES ('2', '0');
INSERT INTO `rating` VALUES ('3', '0');
INSERT INTO `rating` VALUES ('4', '0');
INSERT INTO `rating` VALUES ('2', '0');
INSERT INTO `rating` VALUES ('1', '0');
```

[image]

Comment: Is the last image your expected output? If yes then it is wrong for the given data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT ID
     , COUNT(ID) Count_ID
     , AVG(Rating) AS rating_average
FROM rating
GROUP BY ID;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbd4c/3)

Comment: @mingfish_004 - What's your expected result for the given data?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this query:

```
SELECT id, count_id, AVG(rating_average) FROM rating GROUP BY count_id;
```

Comment: now i get that i think i did not understand, Take a look at hims answer.